# node-mongodb-native save method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native

> Save The save method is a shorthand for upsert if the document
>   contains an `_id`, or an insert if there is no `_id`.

As it says on that page the save method is a shorthand. But there's no example, how do you use the save method.

I'm looking for an example to learn how to use the save method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the save method exactly the same way that you use the insert method.

The only difference is what its result will be if the document already exists.